# How to set the working directory for debugging a Python program in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

How do I execute a Python file with the debugger and specify the working directory for the run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `"cwd"` to `${FileDirname}` in *launch.json* did not work for me; rather, I tried modifying *settings.json*, and actually got a solution.

In the *settings.json* file, add the field:
`"python.terminal.executeInFileDir": true`

After adding this field, my *settings.json* looks something like:

```
{
    "python.terminal.executeInFileDir": true
}
```

This will definitely set the ***cwd*** to the directory that contains your file, as opposed to the root folder of the project.

Comment: I believe ${fileDirname} is case-sensitive as mentioned by Nate demonstrates below.

Answer (score 475):

[@SpeedCoder5's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38623138/vscode-how-to-set-working-directory-for-debugging-a-python-program#comment93079003_38637243) deserves to be an answer.

In `launch.json`, specify a dynamic working directory (i.e. the directory where the currently-open Python file is located) using:

```
"cwd": "${fileDirname}"
```

This takes advantage of the ["variables/variable substitution" feature in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_settings-command-variables-and-input-variables), and the predefined variable `fileDirname`. **Note** these variables are case sensitive. Don't use capital-F `FileDirname`, and be careful of typo's, which might be [the problem with answers like these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76994961/1175496).

Note as comments say, you *might* also need to add the [`purpose` option](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_purpose):

```
"purpose": ["debug-in-terminal"]
```

"Purpose" might be required if using the play button on the top-right of the window, vs <kbd>F5</kbd> or "Run and Debug" in the sidebar.

If you're using the `Python: Current File (Integrated Terminal)` option when you run Python, your `launch.json` file might look like mine, below ([more info on `launch.json` files here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations)).

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
    {
            "name": "Python: Current File (Integrated Terminal)",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "purpose":["debug-in-terminal"]
    }, 

    //... other settings, but I modified the "Current File" setting above ...
}
```

[The `launch.json` file controls the run/debug  settings of your Visual Studio code project](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-versus-attach-configurations); my `launch.json` file was auto-generated by VS Code, in the directory of my current "Open Project". I just edited the file manually to add `"cwd": "${fileDirname}"` as shown above.

Note the `launch.json` file may be specific to your project, or specific to your directory, so confirm you're editing the *correct* `launch.json` ([see comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38623138/how-to-set-the-working-directory-for-debugging-a-python-program-in-vs-code/55072246#comment114115218_55072246))

If you don't have a `launch.json` file, [try this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations):

> To create a launch.json file, open your project folder in VS Code (File > Open Folder) and then select the Configure gear icon on the Debug view top bar.

Per @kbro's comment, you might be prompted to create a `launch.json` file by clicking the Debug button itself:

> When I **clicked on the Debug button on my navigation panel** it said "To customise Run and Debug create a launch.json file." **Clicking on "create..."** opened a dialog asking **what language I was debugging**. In my case I selected Python

Comment: Any way to set this as a default setting for all configurations?

Comment: Be sure you're editing the right launch.json file!  In my experience VS Code creates a .vscode directory in every project folder I open. If yesterday you opened folder parent/ and today you opened parent/child/, you'll have to make changes appropriately.

Comment: There is another file that looks similar to launch.json: workspace[x].code-workspace. It has a 'launch' key. Is this setting there similar to launch.json entries?

Comment: Can I set the folder in the terminal to the folder the script was?. E.g. my last ps1 script line is set-location foo, I want the terminal to be in foo.

Comment: This answer did not work for me, but this one did: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62331298/65326

Comment: What the heck is a launch.json file? Instructions make no sense.

Comment: @Benbob, the launch.json file controls the run/debug settings of your Visual Studio code project; [more info on the launch.json file here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-versus-attach-configurations)

Comment: This current code can be fixed with this. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/18299

Comment: @Serhiy not that I'm aware of, but you can make just make a template `launch.json` locally and copy that information in each time you're creating a new launch.json

Comment: Make sure to debug by hitting F5 or from the left debug pane "Run and Debug" -> Start Debugging. The Debug button on the upper right did not work.

Comment: When I clicked on the Debug button on my navigation panel it said "To customise Run and Debug _create a launch.json file_." Clicking on "create..." opened a dialog asking what language I was debugging. In my case I selected Python.

Comment: TLDR; to run debugger from cwd, add `"purpose":["debug-in-terminal"]` in launch.json

Comment: Thanks @haneulkim , I wasn't aware of the `"purpose"` attribute in the launch.json file, this [link describes it in more detail](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_purpose) I don't know why the `"purpose"` attribute is not mentioned in the [`launch.json` attributes documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launchjson-attributes). I would edit my answer to mentioned `"purpose"`, but I haven't tested it and I worry about comments like "Note: The purpose option can't be used to start the debugger through F5 or Run > Start Debugging"

Comment: Setting `cwd` alone didn't work for me, adding purpose did the trick. VSCode 1.80.1 on linux.

Comment: Thanks @RomanLuštrik , you said that and haneulkim said that, so I added `"purpose": ["debug-in-terminal"]` to the answer

Comment: For me the `"purpose"` isn't needed if you use 'F5' or use the "Run And Debug" sidebar, but *is* required if using the play button on the top-right of my window.   Who knows why they arcane things like this that are counter-intuitive, but it seems to be regular for python :)

Answer (score 66):

Configure the [`cwd`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_cwd) setting in `launch.json` as follows:

```
{
    "name": "Python",
    "type": "python",
    "pythonPath": "python", 
    ...
    "cwd": "<Path to the directory>"
    ...
}
```

Comment: `"cwd": "${fileDirname}"` to run in current directory of open source file

Answer (score 43):

In some cases, it might be also useful to set the `PYTHONPATH` along with the `workspaceFolder`:

```
{
    "name": "Python: Current File",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${file}",
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "env": {
        "PYTHONPATH": "${cwd}"
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, that helped. but I am not sure I understand why is that needed. Can you explain it please?

Comment: @HananShteingart, see Python documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html?highlight=pythonpath#envvar-PYTHONPATH

Comment: "In some cases" – which cases?

Comment: @Ooker in the caes where you have a module but you don't know what is happening in your vscode, this happened to me today, I was prepping an environment for fresh-techies where I needed to set up a module with __main__.py in the root and __init__.py in almost every sub-directory, at least this was my case.

So we needed to run the file, but keep the env for the root as the project root directory

Comment: PYTHONPATH is what you need to set if you are running a module (-m option) and you want the working directory to be different than the main module from which you're running.

Answer (score 38):

This setting helps me: (I am a Windows person)

```
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Launch Program",
  "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}\\app\\js", // set directory here
  "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\app\\js\\server.js", // set start js here
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In order to make this work globally I had to do the following. Updating only the `launch.json` file only solves it in the folder where VSCode currently is open.

1. Locate the `settings.json` file.

   **Windows** `%APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json`

   **macOS** `$HOME/Library/Application\ Support/Code/User/settings.json`

   **Linux** `$HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json`
2. Update the file.

```json
{
    // -- other default or custom settings from before

    "python.terminal.executeInFileDir": true,
    "launch": {
        "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [
            {
                "name": "Python: Current File",
                "type": "python",
                "request": "launch",
                "program": "${file}",
                "console": "integratedTerminal",
                "justMyCode": true,
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
                "purpose": ["debug-in-terminal"]
            }
        ]}
}
```

More information [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_changing-settingsjson) and [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_global-launch-configuration).

Comment: This worked. The additional line of "purpose": ["debug-in-terminal"] was the difference maker for me from the top answer.

Answer (score 6):

I am posting this sample configuration for people who use TypeScript on Node.js

in my project my Node.js server TypeScript files are located in folder Application_ts
and the compiled js files are generated in the folder named Application

because when we run our application in debug mode or start it normally we should start from Application folder which contains the js files
so bellow configuration run debug from root folder where my application_ts also exists and works perfect

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Debug TypeScript in Node.js",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}\\Application\\app.js",
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}\\Application",
        "protocol": "inspector",
        "outFiles": [],
        "sourceMaps": true
    },        
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "attach",
        "name": "Attach to Process",
        "port": 5858,
        "outFiles": [],
        "sourceMaps": true
    }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set up current working directory for debugged program using `cwd` argument in `launch.json`

Answer (score 2):

To set current working directory to whatever file you are executing at the time:

File > Preferences > Settings > Python > Data Science > Execute in File Dir

Thanks brch: [Python in VSCode: Set working directory to python file's path everytime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56776521/python-in-vscode-set-working-directory-to-python-files-path-everytime)

Answer (score 1):

It is important to set PYTHONPATH, you can set it on vscode:

```
{
    "name": "Python debug",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${file}",
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "env": {
        "PYTHONPATH": "${cwd}"
    }
}
```

Or just set it on terminal with:

```
$export PYTHONPATH=/home/user/myproject:$PYTHONPATH
```

Here `/home/user/myproject` is your project path.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and noticed that when running the `which python` command in Terminal in Mac it shows me a different path to what I get when I run the `which python` command in vs code. And also that my file runs properly in the terminal when run using `python filename.py`

So I copied that path from the terminal and pasted it in VS code into Preferences->Settings->Extensions->Python->Default Interpreter Path and it worked. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I use the "justMyCode = false" so I can also debug and jump into the functions that the main script calls.

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.    
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.    
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387    
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I kill debug terminal and re-run.

Comment: This answer does not completely address the question. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76093164/edit) and update your answer with further details.