# vscode working directory when debugging python

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, getcwd

I have a simple problem regarding debugging python script on vscode .

When I open a parent directory on vs code that contains multiple children directories and then I open multiple python files from these children directories.

I then try to debug these files.

the problem is that from the launch.json the cwd is set up to be the parent folder. But I am now running a script in subfolders. and jumping from subfolder to subfolder.

So changing the  "cwd": "workspaceRoot" every now and then isn't practical for me

is there a way that the debugger will always use the current folder of the debugged script file as the current directory??

p.s this question didn't help me [stackoverfollow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38623138/vscode-how-to-set-working-directory-for-debug)

Answer (score 13):

try setting "cwd": "", in launch.json,

at least it works in the latest version, I can run python modules from root and subdirectories without changing launch settings
(vs.code 1.16.1, python extension 0.7)

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem: I had a subfolder with Python script and some data file. While debugging a script, I was getting an error with message, that the data file could not be found.

Here is the debug configuration which solved this problem:

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}\\${relativeFileDirname}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answer didn't solve my problem. It worked if I put a dot in the current working dir configuration in `launch.json`. Here it is:

```
  "configurations": [
    {
      "cwd": ".",
      "name": "Python: Current file",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${file}",
      "console": "integratedTerminal"
    },
   ]
```

To open the launch configuration just go to the debug tab and click in the top gear icon.

I'm using VSCode 1.44.2.

Answer (score 0):

Per [How to make VSCode run your code from the location of the code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70419135) Add `"cwd": "${fileDirname}"` in the launch.json file.  `.vscode/launch.json` should look something like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        }
    ]
}
```