# How to make VSCode run your code from the location of the code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I keep on getting `Module Not Found` errors in Python and by printing out `os.getcwd()`, I found that VSCode seems to be running things from the workspace folder (the top-level folder in the editor) rather than the folder that the code is in. Thus, it can't find the the modules because all of my relative import and path-changing code doesn't work.

I did some research and found the option `"python.terminal.executeInFileDir": true` in settings, which seems like it should change this, but when I press <kbd>F5</kbd>, the code still seems to be run out of the workspace folder.

How can I get the code to be run out of the same folder that the file is in when I run my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And you can add `"cwd": "${fileDirname}"` in the launch.json file.

Answer (score 2):

When pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>, you're using the *debugger*.

The debugger's settings are separate from the `"python.terminal.executeInFileDir": true`, and can be changed by creating a `launch.json` file (or editing the existing one) as described in more detail [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging).

Specifically, you will want to add `"cwd": "${file}/.."` to your `launch.json` file. This will set the directory for debugging to be the encapsulating folder of the file you are running.