# Why does the python open() function not create a .txt file inside the same folder as the host file?

Tags: python

I am a beginner, working on python code in Visual Studio. I have created a dir `Test_Folder` with the following python file `Test.py`:

```
new_file = open('README.txt','w')
new_file.close()
```

The resulting file `README.txt` fro, `Test.py` is being created outside the `Test_Folder`:

```
my_dir
   ├── Test_Folder          
   │   ├── Test.py
   ├── README.txt
```

Why does this happen? And how can I create the text file inside the same directory?

Comment: Please share your code as pasted text, not as an image.

Comment: Are you running the .py file from inside Test_Folder (i.e. does your command prompt say you are in the same dir as the .py file)?

Comment: You are probably in an other working directory. Use this to figure which one: `print (os.getcwd())` and use this to change it `os.chdir()`.

Answer (score 2):

The file is created in the "current working directory" (cwd), which is the folder from where you ran the command `python my_script.py`.

If you run this:

```
cd /path/to/Test_folder
python Test.py
```

the file will be created in `/path/to/Test_folder`.

If you run

```
cd /path/to
python Test_folder/Test.py
```

the file will be created in `/path/to`.

If you want to see what is your concrete "current working directory" within your script:

```
>>> import os
>>> print(os.getcwd())
'/path/to/your_current_working_directory'
```

Since your run your script using VSCode, you can configure your "cwd" from the `launch.json` file in your project's folder. See [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38637243/1887976) for more information:

```
{
    // [...]
    "cwd": "<Path to the directory>"
}
```