# How to run python interactive in current file's directory in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When executing `"Run Selection/Line in Python Terminal"` command in VSCode, terminal's current working directory is the workspace root directory. How can we set current directory of terminal to the **current file**'s directory when running the selection/line?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56776521/11107541

Answer (score 37):

In "User Settings", use the search bar to look for "python.terminal.executeInFileDir" and set (=) its value to "true" instead of "false".

Comment: I dont think this seems to work. interactive window is related to the `notebook file root` settings

Comment: this doesn't answer the original question but it was the answer I was looking for so have an upvote +1

Comment: I don't see 'User settings' in current VS Code This worked for me on one computer but on a different station 11-2021. I went to general settings, typed python.terminal.executeInFileDir and set the chechkmark for both User and Workspace. But, when I try to run the a file os.getcwd() gives me the Open Folder location, which is one directory up, not the file's location. Any idea?

Comment: This works for "Run Python File" in VS Code 1.84.2 (but not for the problem in the question). Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 14):

**Update following release 2019.10.44104**

Following release 2019.10.44104 of the VS Code python extension, you can now set the `python.dataScience.notebookFileRoot` to `${fileDirname}` to directly start the python interactive window in the directory of the file you're running.

Note that the root directory will not change if you then run code from another file unless you interrupt/restart the kernel (or close VS Code). On this aspect, see the following [comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/4441#issuecomment-549427825) and the corresponding [github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/3104).

---

For the Python Interactive Window, the setting you're looking for is `python.dataScience.notebookFileRoot`. However, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54794976/11896053) to a similar question,

> Always opening on the file location (without having to set `notebookFileRoot` to an absolute path per folder) is not supported via the `notebookFileRoot` setting. The VSCode variables such as `${fileDirname}` are specific to task and debug configuration files (`launch.json` and `task.json`).

See also the associated [github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/4441).

As indicated, you can still set this setting to a specific absolute path, which might be enough if you're mainly working on a single project at a time.

Alternatively, you could also add the following code at the top of your script/notebook:

```
import os
os.chdir('absolute-path-to-workingDir')
```

Comment: As of 2022, I don't think option is available anymore (running VSCode 1.73.1).

Answer (score 13):

I used the option Run -> Add Configuration (or Open configuration, if available)
This will open your current 'launch.json' file.
Now you may add this line to the configuration wanted (in my case was Python):

```
"cwd": "${fileDirname}"
```

This line will make VSCode to run your stuff in the same folder as the file is being executed.

You can get more details in this link:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference

Here is my full json file (just for reference):

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [                
                    
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"            
            
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This works for "Run and Debug: Python: Current File", but not for the problem in the question. Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

you need to go to `file/preferences/user settings` and click the "{}" icon at the top right of the window. After that, put this setting in: `"terminal.integrated.cwd": "C:\\Users\\myUser\\",` and after that wherever your terminal's directory happens to be. This answer is not the most inaccurate cause im still a noob myself at using vscode so if someone more experienced with it could reply to this thread it would be great.

Answer (score 1):

There is no straightforward way to achieve this yet. In search for a better solution, I have a workaround with the [Terminal Here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Tyriar.vscode-terminal-here) extension in the VScode Marketplace. This extension allows you to open an integrated terminal in the current file's directory. This extension combined with a few more steps and you should get the desired behavior.

- Once the extension is installed, make sure your file window is in focus, and press `ctrl+shift+p` and execute `Terminal Here: Create Terminal`. This will create a new terminal in the file's directory.
- Type `python` in the terminal to launch the Python interpreter.
- Now, position the cursor on the  line you wish to execute and press `ctrl+shift+p` and execute `Terminal: Run selected text in active terminal`. This will run that line of code in the open python interpreter.

The first two steps are required only for the first time you run a code selection in the Python interpreter in the current file's directory. All subsequent selections can be run with the third step. To make things quicker, you could attach custom [keybindings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings) to the first and last steps.

Answer (score 0):

This options will help you.
File->Preferences->Settings. 
Add or edit the below setting.

`terminal.integrated.shell.windows": ""`

From the next terminal it will be reflected.

And add .profile to your default shell and add default path to it.

More information at: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal

Answer (score -1):

this issue is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38623138/vscode-how-to-set-working-directory-for-debug). The solution is to config the `launch.json` file in `.vscode` folder

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30695822)

Comment: The referred tutorial addresses a *different* problem: *debugging* a Python file.