# vscode - read file from current folder where .py file is

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm very new to programming, and to vscode.

I'm learning Python and currently I am learning about working with files.

The path looks like this: `/home/anewuser/learning/chapter10`.

The problem: completely basic "read file in python" lesson does not work in vscode because `no such file or directory` error raises when running my .py file, located in `~/learning/chapter10`. But vscode wants that my .txt file I am supposed to open in python, to be in `~/learning` directory, then it works. I don't like this behaviour.

All I want is to be able to read file placed in the directory where the .py file is. How to do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please check [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To help people understand your problem, you would need to post some code and highlight, if possible, which part of your code is causing the problem. In your case, it sounds like a folder issue. How did you use the Python built-in `open` function?

Comment: @Al-un It is the most basic code to read a file: `with open('pi_digits.txt') as file_object:
    contents = file_object.read()
    print(contents)` Error:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anewuser/learning/chapter10/file_reader.py", line 1, in <module>
    with open('pi_digits.txt') as file_object:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pi_digits.txt'` When i put both .py and pi_digits.txt in `~/learning/chapter10`, this error happens. When I put 'pi_digits.txt' in `~/learning` directory, it works. What to do make it work in the same directory? Thanks!

Comment: Also, this code works fine when run directly in a terminal. No errors. Other IDE like KDevelop also has no problem with it, but it does not work in vscode.

Comment: Please post the code in your question, you can edit it ^^

Comment: As for your question itself, you may have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165749/open-file-in-a-relative-location-in-python

Answer (score 1):

Because in your case `~/learning` is the default cwd (current working directory), VSCode looks for `pi_digits.txt` in that location. If you put `pi_digits.txt` beside `file_reader.py` (which is located at `~/learning/chapter10`), you'll have to specify the path (by prepending `chapter10/` to the `.txt` file).

So you should do this:

```py
with open('chapter10/pi_digits.txt') as file_object:
    contents = file_object.read()
    print(contents)
```

---

If you want to change the default current working directory (for example you want to change it to `~/learning/chapter10`), you'll have to do the following:

**~/learning/chapter10/file_reader.py**

```py
import os  # first you need to import the module 'os'

# set the cwd to 'chapter10'
os.chdir('chapter10')

# now 'file_reader.py' and 'pi_digits.txt' are both in the cwd
with open('pi_digits.txt') as file_object:
    contents = file_object.read()
    print(contents)
```

With `os.chdir('chapter10')` you've set `chapter10` as the default cwd, in which VSCode now will look for `pi_digits.txt`.

For detailed information about `os.chdir()` you can read through [the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=chdir#os.chdir) or take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810743/how-to-set-the-current-working-directory) on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

In "User Settings", use the search bar to look for "python.terminal.executeInFileDir" and set (=) its value to "true" instead of "false".

I took this answer from here
[How to run python interactive in current file's directory in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53900141/how-to-run-python-interactive-in-current-files-directory-in-visual-studio-code)
this is my first time putting an answer on StackOverflow
so I apologize if I didn't do it the right way