# Cannot Use Anaconda in VSCode Despite Working in PyCharm

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Regarding the problem that Anaconda cannot be used normally in VSCode but can be used normally in PyCharm:

The code can run normally in PyCharm, but I have questions about the document in VSCode and why it cannot analyze my file normally. I cannot find the error. Is it because of the setting problem of Anaconda?
I have tried many times but have yet to find a solution. I have already downloaded Anaconda. Is it because of my path setting problem?
I switched to the editor that comes with my Mac, but it showed that it could not be parsed and imported from the source.
Is it because of the editor logic and path settings?
I hope someone can help me guide and provide a solution so that my VSCode can run Anaconda normally.

[Traceback Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evMBL.png)

[Code Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PnnO.jpg)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/junhaowu/Documents/Code/demo/指尖文字识别.py", line 157, in <module>
    gClass.call_url()
  File "/Users/junhaowu/Documents/Code/demo/指尖文字识别.py", line 130, in call_url
    body = self.get_body()
  File "/Users/junhaowu/Documents/Code/demo/指尖文字识别.py", line 112, in get_body
    audioData = self.imgRead((self.AudioPath))
  File "/Users/junhaowu/Documents/Code/demo/指尖文字识别.py", line 57, in imgRead
    with open(path, 'rb') as fo:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '指尖文字识别CH.jpg'
```

```py
import requests
import datetime
import hashlib
import base64
import hmac
import json


class get_result(object):
    def __init__(self, host):
        # todo
        # 应用ID（到控制台获取）
        self.APPID = "2552e120"
        # 接口APISercet（到控制台指尖文字服务页面获取）
        self.Secret = "SECRET"
        # 接口APIKey（到控制台指尖文字服务页面获取）
        self.APIKey = "APIKEY"

        # 以下为POST请求
        self.Host = host
        self.RequestUri = "/v2/ocr"
        # 设置url
        # print(host)
        self.url = "https://"+host+self.RequestUri
        self.HttpMethod = "POST"
        self.Algorithm = "hmac-sha256"
        self.HttpProto = "HTTP/1.1"

        # 设置当前时间
        curTime_utc = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        self.Date = self.httpdate(curTime_utc)
        # 设置测试图片文件
        # todo
        self.AudioPath = "指尖文字识别CH.jpg"
        self.BusinessArgs = {
                "ent": "fingerocr",
                "mode": "finger+ocr",
                "method": "dynamic",
                "resize_w": 1088,
                "resize_h": 1632,
            }

    def imgRead(self, path):
        with open(path, 'rb') as fo:
            return fo.read()

    def hashlib_256(self, res):
        m = hashlib.sha256(bytes(res.encode(encoding='utf-8'))).digest()
        result = "SHA-256=" + base64.b64encode(m).decode(encoding='utf-8')
        return result

    def httpdate(self, dt):
        """
        Return a string representation of a date according to RFC 1123
        (HTTP/1.1).

        The supplied date must be in UTC.

        """
        weekday = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"][dt.weekday()]
        month = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep",
                 "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"][dt.month - 1]
        return "%s, %02d %s %04d %02d:%02d:%02d GMT" % (weekday, dt.day, month,
                                                        dt.year, dt.hour, dt.minute, dt.second)

    def generateSignature(self, digest):
        signatureStr = "host: " + self.Host + "\n"
        signatureStr += "date: " + self.Date + "\n"
        signatureStr += self.HttpMethod + " " + self.RequestUri \
                        + " " + self.HttpProto + "\n"
        signatureStr += "digest: " + digest
        signature = hmac.new(bytes(self.Secret.encode(encoding='utf-8')),
                             bytes(signatureStr.encode(encoding='utf-8')),
                             digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()
        result = base64.b64encode(signature)
        return result.decode(encoding='utf-8')

    def init_header(self, data):
        digest = self.hashlib_256(data)
        # print(digest)
        sign = self.generateSignature(digest)
        authHeader = 'api_key="%s", algorithm="%s", ' \
                     'headers="host date request-line digest", ' \
                     'signature="%s"' \
                     % (self.APIKey, self.Algorithm, sign)
        # print(authHeader)
        headers = {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Method": "POST",
            "Host": self.Host,
            "Date": self.Date,
            "Digest": digest,
            "Authorization": authHeader
        }
        return headers

    def get_body(self):
        audioData = self.imgRead((self.AudioPath))
        content = base64.b64encode(audioData).decode(encoding='utf-8')
        postdata = {
            "common": {"app_id": self.APPID},
            "business": self.BusinessArgs,
            "data": {
                "image": content,
            }
        }
        body = json.dumps(postdata)
        # print(body)
        return body

    def call_url(self):
        if self.APPID == '' or self.APIKey == '' or self.Secret == '':
            print('Appid 或APIKey 或APISecret 为空！请打开demo代码，填写相关信息。')
        else:
            code = 0
            body = self.get_body()
            headers = self.init_header(body)
            # print(self.url)
            response = requests.post(self.url, data=body, headers=headers, timeout=8)
            status_code = response.status_code
            # print(response.content)
            if status_code != 200:
                # 鉴权失败
                print("Http请求失败，状态码：" + str(status_code) + "，错误信息：" + response.text)
                print("请根据错误信息检查代码，接口文档：https://www.xfyun.cn/doc/words/finger-word-discern/API.html")
            else:
                # 鉴权成功
                respData = json.loads(response.text)
                # print(respData)
                out_data = respData['data']['finger_ocr']['sent']['content']
                print(out_data)
                # 以下仅用于调试
                code = str(respData["code"])
                if code != '0':
                    print("请前往https://www.xfyun.cn/document/error-code?code=" + code + "查询解决办法")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # 示例:  host="rest-api.xfyun.cn"域名形式
    host = "tyocr.xfyun.cn"
    # 初始化类
    gClass = get_result(host)
    gClass.call_url()
```

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) -- make sure the _text of the question itself_ contains everything needed to understand the question and learn from its answers.

Comment: Where's your `指尖文字识别CH.jpg`?

Comment: Is it a problem with my software configuration?

Comment: I have successfully uploaded the code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vscode - read file from current folder where .py file is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55191397/vscode-read-file-from-current-folder-where-py-file-is)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).