# How to set the running file path of jupyter in VScode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter

When I use the jupyter extension in VScode and run a line of code in jupyter to save a file using relative path，I found the file(iris_tree.dot) in another file. It's just like i debug/run the code in another file path. How can I set the correct path of the jupyter runner?

```py
#%%
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
export_graphviz(
tree_clf,
out_file="iris_tree.dot",
feature_names=iris.feature_names[2:],
class_names=iris.target_names,
rounded=True,
filled=True
)
```

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/56091981/6875391, I've changed the setting "python.terminal.executeInFileDir" (Ctrl+Shift+P search "User setting" then search "python.terminal.executeInFileDir") and it looks like pypath was updated

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I'm one of the developers on this extension. By default we follow the VSCode pattern of working directory as opposed to the Jupyter pattern. Meaning that we use the root of the currently open workspace folder as the current working directory for starting jupyter notebooks. That might be what is confusing you here.

To get around this you can either set cwd in your notebook code as redhatvicky mentioned or you can change the default current working directory in the following VSCode setting.

Jupyter -> Notebook File Root

Since you can change that setting per workspace you can have it always default to a specific location when working in just the workspace that contains your file.

Edit 2/16/22 New setting location

Comment: @YANGSULIU please mark this as the correct answer :) Then it's easier for people to find it.

Comment: what should the setting be exactly?  I have  `${fileDirname}` and it's not working.

Comment: It seems like this setting silently fails if it doesn't like the path. For example, it doesn't seem to expand `~` to be your home directory.

Comment: This is not working for me for R Jupyter notebooks.

Comment: Setting `${fileDirname}` is not working for me either. This is a seriously annoying problem...

Comment: This solution works exclusively with local jupyter instances. A [recent update](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/blob/85dcde7742a45e37eddc47d41de76ae728883aa3/package.nls.json#L177) includes comments that explicitly rule out using this option on remote servers.

Answer (score 61):

Just update the value of "Notebook File Root" to `${workspaceFolder}` or `${fileDirname}`.

[image]

Comment: For quick copy and paste: `${workspaceFolder}`  OR `${fileDirname}`

Comment: I found this more helpful, I didn't see under settings  "Python -> data science ..."  as @Ian Huff's answer said

Comment: This is the correct answer, at least at this moment.

Comment: If you're having trouble finding this setting, go to the Extensions icon on the left panel of vscode (looks like 4 blocks) and search for Jupyter. Just under the search, on the Jupyter extension, click the gear. Scroll down to  "Notebook File Root".

Comment: Another way to find this setting (on Mac) is to go to Code -> Settings -> Settings and search for "Notebook File Root" in the search bar.

Answer (score 6):

@Ian Huff's answer is still valid, however the setting seems to have changed location since then.

Instead of "Python -> Data Science -> Notebook File Root", it's now "Jupyter -> Notebook File Root"

Comment: This is not a valid answer for the question

Comment: Sorry about that @AnkitSangwan. How am I supposed to share that new information concerning a previous answer (since I am not yet allowed to comment on others' answers).

Comment: After you reach a reputation of 50 you will be able to comment. Until then try to answer those questions which don't need any clarification or something.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems quite confusing and I am unable to post a comment. Please follow this [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support). As per your question, I think the issue is you need to select the correct python interpreter by **CTRL+SHIFT+P** and then `Python: Select Interpreter` to select the correct conda environment or a conda interpreter. Otherwise you can try and execute the following code to change your directory before any other command:

```
import os
try:
    os.chdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'path_to_folder_to_have_the_file')) # '.' if the path is to current folder
    print(os.getcwd())
except:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally you can change the working directory by using "os.chdir(NEW_PATH)"

One another Suggestion is that , You can set the location to save the image from the code itself.

Here below is the code which might help you.

```
from __future__ import division, print_function, unicode_literals

# Common imports
import numpy as np
import os

# to make this notebook's output stable across runs
np.random.seed(42)

# To plot pretty figures
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['axes.labelsize'] = 14
plt.rcParams['xtick.labelsize'] = 12
plt.rcParams['ytick.labelsize'] = 12

# Where to save the figures
PROJECT_ROOT_DIR = "."
CHAPTER_ID = "decision_trees"

def image_path(fig_id):
    return os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT_DIR, "images", CHAPTER_ID, fig_id)

def save_fig(fig_id, tight_layout=True):
    print("Saving figure", fig_id)
    if tight_layout:
        plt.tight_layout()
    print(image_path(fig_id) + ".png")
    plt.savefig(image_path(fig_id) + ".png", format='png', dpi=300)

save_fig("Fig-01-6TFG")
```

Comment: THANKS! I can achieve the same goal if I use the Absolute Path to save the file. But  I want to make it certain why this happen and how i can rewrite the settings to ensure every code file can run in the correct file path.

Comment: one way to change the default directory to use for notebooks ,permanently is to change the config files. Firstly in the cmdline, type:
 
 $> ipython profile create
 
 to initialize a profile with the default configuration file. Secondly, in file ipython_notebook_config.py, uncomment and edit this line:
 
 c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = 'Z:\\username_example\folder_that_you_whant'
 
 you can also follow the below approach :
 
 ipython notebook --notebook-dir=/path/to/specific/directory

Answer (score -1):

A manual approach might also be useful in some cases.
Open **VScode's file explorer** by pressing the default hotkeys:
`CMD + Shift + E` (on MacOS) / `Ctrl + Shift + E` (on Windows).

On the opened left pane you'll see a list of files, with the currently open file highlighted.
right-click on the desired file name (highlighted) and select `Copy Path` or `Copy Relative Path`, depending on your needs.

The file path is now in your clipboard, so simply press `CMD + v` / `Ctrl + v` to paste it where its required.