# How to set working directory for all Jupyter notebooks in notebooks folder to parent folder (vscode)?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I have this project structure:

```
project
--notebooks
    -notebook1.ipynb
    -notebook2.ipynb
  --utils
    -functions.py
somefile.py
```

I want to be able to import functions from utils folder into my notebooks. However the cwd for the notebooks is the notebooks folder. Is there a way to set my cwd for all my notebooks without having to use os.chdir() in each one?

Any help would be appreciated!

I've looked around for various solutions. I want to use Jupyter in vscode so opening the Juypter lab from the parent directory is not the right option for me.

Comment: Do either of these help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/55491046/11107541 and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/150757