# How to set the file path of a remote jupyter notebook in VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Is it possible to set the working directory of a **remote** Jupyter `.ipynb` notebook? This problem is similar to [How to set the running file path of jupyter in VScode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55491046/how-to-set-the-running-file-path-of-jupyter-in-vscode), but the solution provided in that question looks like it applies **only** to local instances of Jupyter, **not remote instances**.

When connecting to a remote server and kernel from VSCode, the working directory where the remote jupyter session was started is used as the working directory.

This means that if the notebook instance is launched in `/home/foouser/src/`, relative imports inside each project folder will not behave as expected. Inside `project2`, `main.ipynb` will not be able to execute `from library import resource`. This will result in a `ModuleNotFoundError`.

```
.
└── /home/foouser/src/
    ├── project1/
    │   └── main.ipynb
    ├── project2/
    │   ├── library/
    │   │   └── resorce.py
    │   └── main.ipynb
    └── project3/
        ├── ham/
        │   └── spam.py
        └── main.ipynb
```

### My Environment

- VSCode 1.84.2 running on Mac Os
- Jupyter Lab 4.0.9 running on Raspberry Pi OS (Debian Bookworm)
- Python 3.11 running on the Pi
- VSCode Jupyter Extension v2023.10.1100000000

### Steps to Reproduce

1. Launch Jupyter on a raspberry pi in `/home/foouser/src/` - `$ jupyter lab --ip=192.168.1.99 --no-browser`
2. Connect to raspberry pi from VS Code over SSH
3. Browse to an `.ipynb` file in `/home/foouser/src/project3/main.ipynb` and open
4. Set kernel to remote kernel by pasting URI to Jupyter server into VSCode
5. Try to run a cell with a relative import `from ham import spam` --> results in `ModuleNotFoundError`

### What I've Tried

**Launching the notebook instance from `/home/foouser/src/project2`**

This solves the problem of the relative imports in project 2, but makes it really hard to work on project1 or project3. I have to either start multiple instances of jupyter in each project directory, or stop one instance and start another. This is not at all ideal as the remote host is a raspberry pi with limited resources; everything kind of grinds to a halt.

**Setting `"jupyter.notebookFileRoot": "${fileDirname}"` in `.vscode/settings.json`**

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55491046/how-to-set-the-running-file-path-of-jupyter-in-vscode) looks tantalizing, but after much faffing around, it appears that this may be a red-herring. I came across [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/blob/85dcde7742a45e37eddc47d41de76ae728883aa3/package.nls.json#L177) that states that the variable is only for *local* instances.

<strike>**Creating a helper function in a python file to detect the working dir**</strike>

**EDIT:** This doesn't work reliably

This is a [**fugly** hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73673295/5530152), but it works. I'm sure this will bite me in the butt later.

dir_helper.py

```py
import os

def get_local_folder():
    return os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

Then running the following cell:

```py
from dir_helper import get_local_folder
import os
os.chdir(get_local_folder())
```

Comment: maybe you should add folders `/full/path/to/project2`, etc. to `sys.path` before `import`

Comment: That works, as does running `os.chdir(/full/path/to/project2)` at the start of each notebook, but it's cumbersome and if the full path changes for whatever reason, every single notebook needs to be updated. 

This is a real threat if multiple people are working on a project and store the project in different locations on their devices.

Comment: frankly, standard method is to use `os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))` and it is not `"fugly hack"`

Comment: @furas: 
This does not appear to work from within a remote jupyter notebook. Try running this in a remote notebook and you will reliably get `NameError: name '__file__' is not defined`

Comment: This also reliably fails from within a jupyter notebook running within jupyter lab. You can try to dump this into a `.py` file and import that (as I tried above), but your relative imports won't reliably work if you started your jupyter lab session somewhere other than your project directory (e.g. you started in ~/src/ instead of ~/src/project1).  Within a jupyter lab session the solution I outlined above with the `dir_helper.py`, this works great. Within a VSCode Jupyter session, it reliably fails with `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_path'`

Comment: some use `argv[0]` instead of `__file__` - maybe it will help

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly, but it sounds like you want something like what is requested in this feature-request issue ticket: [Relative Path not work for Remote Kernel #8771](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/8771). I suggest that you give that issue ticket a thumbs up to show support for it. You can also subscribe to it to get notified about discussion and progress. Please avoid making noisy comments there like ones that just consist of "+1" / "bump".

[There's a workaround there](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/8771#issuecomment-1487939477) posted by [Anar Z. Yusifov](https://github.com/thoth291) (put it in your [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson)):

> ```json
> "jupyter.runStartupCommands": [
>     "import os",
>     "__t=os.path.dirname(__vsc_ipynb_file__)",
>     "%cd {__t}",
>     "del __t"
> ],
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've subscribed to that thread. To be clear, where is the logical place for this? In each project directory, or the local settings file on the machine where I'm using VSCode locally or somewhere else? I'm a little hazy on how VSCode processes these and in what order.

Comment: @AaronCiuffo I think local user settings. the setting isn't supported in workspace settings.

Comment: I'll give that a try. Thanks for the tip.