# VSCode Python Debugger FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

Let's define a simple folder structure like this:

```
project
+---code
|       main.py
|
\---data
        foo.txt
```

main.py:

```
foo_path = "./../data/foo.txt"

with open(foo_path) as f:
    s = f.read()
    print(s)
```

This code works well while running normally using `python main.py` command, but it throws the following error while debugging using VSCode Python Debugger.

```
Exception has occurred: FileNotFoundError
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: './../data/foo.txt'
  File "C:\Users\user\Workspaces\project\code\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    with open(foo_path) as f:
```

I am using VSCode with Python 3.7.1 Anaconda version in Windows 10. I know that the file path is like a Linux path, but it works while running normally. I couldn't find any open issue in [the GitHub repo of Python VSCode Extension](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python). Is this a common error, or am I doing something wrong?

Also, if I define `foo_path = ".\\..\\data\\foo.txt"`, it behaves same as the previous one. It runs well normally and gives the same error while debugging.

How can I fix this without using extra package like `os.path` or using the full file path?

EDIT: I tried in Ubuntu 18.04, and it behaves same.

Comment: I'm having this exact same issue. Strange part, is the terminal says: FileNotFoundError
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'path/to/file.py'.   But I can option+click on 'path/to/file.py' and it opens the file in VS code.  Did you ever find a solution that worked for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`cwd` option in your debug configuration](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_cwd), but I would advise you simply don't hard-code the path and use `pathlib` or `os.path` to specify the file relative to the location of `__file__` (I'm not quite sure why you want to avoid those modules).

Comment: That is not about avoiding those modules. I thought, normal run and debug should work same, I just didn't want the answers including `os.path`  and `pathlib` . But the `cwd` option makes sense. Its default is `${workspaceFolder}`. If `foo_path = "data/foo.txt"`, it works. Or, I can change `cwd` as you suggest. Thank you.

Comment: Didn't work for me, but `"cwd": "${fileDirname}"` did, which isn't mentioned in the link, but here: [set cwd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38623138/vscode-how-to-set-working-directory-for-debugging-a-python-program). Note to myself, should I land in this duplicate question, again :)

Comment: the pathlib's `p = Path('my.csv').resolve().__str__(); with open(p, 'r') as csv_file:` doesn't helped..

Comment: @Oleg You probably want `(Path(__file__).parent / 'my.csv').open('r') as csv_file: ...`. And I would advise against calling `__str__()`/`str()` on a path object. Not only is it usually unnecessary (thanks to https://peps.python.org/pep-0519/), it can lead to odd errors if someone passes something like `None` as a file path by accident. If you truly need the string of a path, use `os.fsdecode()`.

Comment: @BrettCannonq i have string issues for using Path objects as path - all the time! so much annoying, just take any app from outside the std.lib. as for solution - thanks, i will try!

Answer (score 4):

##### Exactly. I faced the same issue, and this is how I fixed mine

On the inbuilt terminal, inside vscode:

- change the directory to where your code lives. For example:

```
cd /path_to_your_code_dir/
```

in my case, it was:

```
cd /repos/
```

because my code was here -> `~/repos/main.py`

- Then run the VSCode Python Debugger again

.
(edited)

### I found the reason for this error and a better way to fix it

> The error occurs because the python debugger executes files in the terminal from the current open folder (by default)
> But you can change this behavior, to use execute in the file's directory:

- Go to vscode settings (or use the shortcut key: **ctrl+comma** )
- then search for this `@ext:ms-python.python execute` in the settings
- you would see the settings "Execute in File Dir"
- then check the box, *to execute code in file's directory instead of the current open folder*
- go back to your code and re-run (i.e clicking the debugger run button)

> This eliminates the FileNotFoundError when you know your file is sitting in the right place, and you are pointing in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

As for me, I had my main.py in a folder B inside a folder A. If I opened VSCode in folder A, and tried to debug main.py, I got a **FileNotFoundExeption**for 'file.txt'. When I opened VSCode in folder B and did the same, it worked.

```
folder A
-- folder B
|     main.py
|     file.txt
```

*(Turning Setting `Python > Terminal: Execute In File Dir` as proposed in another comment did not solve the issue for me)*

Answer (score 0):

I use pathlib, which always works, both runtime and during debugging:

```
import os
import pathlib

foo_path = os.path.join(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute(), "..", "foo.txt")

with open(foo_path) as f:
    s = f.read()
    print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. code exists in `/src` directory
2. debugger `cwd` was pointing to root `/`

`/src/foo.py`

code:

```
file = open('../files/temp.txt')
```

`launch.json` - producing the `FileNotFound` error:

```
    "configurations": [
        
        {
            "name": "Python: File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },

    ]
}
```

Fixed the `cwd`:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        
        {
            "name": "Python: File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/src"
        },

    ]
}
```

Changing the `cwd` (in launch.json) to point to the directory where my `source_code` file exits fixed the issue.