# VSCode file not found for file in current directory

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a basic python script to open a file. The script and the file being opened are in the same folder.

If I use the command line in the folder, it works just fine, but from VS Code I'm getting a File not found error.

[image]

I have set via the preferences the CWD and it put this in my settings.json

```
"python.testing.cwd": "${fileDirname}",
```

From the terminal window in VS Code when I run the code (F5) I can see it's even changing directory to where the program is.

```
(base) C:\Users\Neil>cd "e:\DATA\Projects\Modelling\Long Drop Data" && cmd /C E:\DATA\Dev\MiniConda\python.exe c:\Users\Neil\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.6.24221\pythonFiles\ptvsd_launcher.py --default --client --host localhost --port 50397 "e:\DATA\Projects\Modelling\Long Drop Data\read_data.py" "
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you share the error message as well? If any other details then `File not found.`

Comment: Yes, sure. I'll update the message. It is simply it is looking in the 'default' folder and not the folder where the script it, for the file so it does not exist.

Comment: One more thing. What is `launch.json` - can you past that too here.

Comment: This might be helpful in the configuration. Given `cwd` param for `launch.json`.

Ref:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38623138/vscode-how-to-set-working-directory-for-debug

Comment: Thanks, I'm just opening a single script file not a folder, and I didn't really want to go down the route of having to create an entire launcher file every time I want to do something like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can either specify the current working directory you want in your `launch.json` or you will need to calculate the location of the file you want to read more concretely, e.g. `pathlib.Path(__file__).with_name(filename)` if the file is kept next to the Python file. (The testing setting only affects when you run tests via the extension.)

Answer (score 1):

filename = 'file.csv'
facing the same issue I stumbled to a solution and it worked without any complex reworking of settings. In my case the file is not being "trusted" nor is the folder within vs code. When I opened the folder from the file menu (shortcut ctrl+k followed by ctrl+o) I was prompted to trust the authors of the folder/its contents. Thereafter my python code works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).