# VS Code debugger cannot find the file, but file exists

Tags: python, opencv, visual-studio-code, atom-editor, vscode-debugger

I'm using VS Code for Python (anaconda package and OpenCV).

I'm debugging the program (pressing F5) and I'm getting the error below.

[image: it says File not found/ but the file is there when I run via terminal]

**code I'm getting the error with**

```
import cv2 as cv
import os
import numpy as np

pathsyn = os.path.realpath("synset_words.txt")

print("path", pathsyn)

syn = open(pathsyn,"r").read().strip().split("\n")

syncls = [r[r.find(" ") +1:] for r in syn]

vid = cv.VideoCapture(0)

net = cv.dnn.readNetFromCaffe("Classifiers/model/bvlc_googlenet.prototxt","Classifiers/model/bvlc_googlenet.caffemodel")
```

though the both `synset_words.txt,AI02.py` files are in the same directory

[both are in the same directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckMqj.png)

if I modify the code to

```
pathsyn = os.path.realpath("OpenCV/synset_words.txt")
```

then it works.

```
import cv2 as cv
import os
import numpy as np

pathsyn = os.path.realpath("OpenCV/synset_words.txt")

print("path", pathsyn)

syn = open(pathsyn,"r").read().strip().split("\n")

syncls = [r[r.find(" ") +1:] for r in syn]

vid = cv.VideoCapture(0)

net = cv.dnn.readNetFromCaffe("OpenCV/Classifiers/model/bvlc_googlenet.prototxt","OpenCV/Classifiers/model/bvlc_googlenet.caffemodel")
```

[Directories; .vscode is outside of the OpenCV folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWHok.png)

this is because `.vscode` the folder is in the previous directory and my `AI02.py` and `synset_words.txt` is in OpenCV folder.

Directory where VS Code is finding the file (where the .vscode folder also):

```
C:\Users\user\Documents\Python Scripts
```

but the file is in (where vs code should direct debugger like terminal):

```
C:\Users\user\Documents\Python Scripts\OpenCV
```

Comment: Could you post your codes directly instead of the screenshot? It is hard to review them on the screenshot.

Comment: @GenWan changes have been made for easier understanding. pls see the question again. thank you.

Comment: Could you please print `os.getcwd()` and post the result here?

Comment: @HamzaHathoute `current path os.getcwd():  c:\Users\user\Documents\Python Scripts` 
and the path should be 
`c:\Users\user\Documents\Python Scripts\OpenCV`.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Try setting the current working directory to the one you need using `os.chdir(path)` before `pathsyn = ...`

Comment: @HamzaHathoute that may work, but this would be a temporary solution. I want to set VS Code debugger to `c:\Users\user\Documents\Python Scripts\OpenCV` as my default directory instead of `c:\Users\user\Documents\Python Scripts`

Comment: Did you try https://stackoverflow.com/q/38623138/9406615 ?

Comment: @HamzaHathoute Wow!! Thanks... Work like a charm!! :)

Answer (score 9):

In the `launch.config` change the CWD to the folder **OR** just use the command mentioned below:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            ....,
            "cwd" : "${workspaceFolder}/${relativeFileDirname}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Not working for me, still showing could not find file

Answer (score 1):

> Try setting the current working directory to the one you need using os.chdir(path) before pathsyn = ... – Hamza Hathoute 4 hours ago
>
> @HamzaHathoute that may work, but this would be a temporary solution. I want to set VS Code debugger to c:\Users\user\Documents\Python Scripts\OpenCV as my default directory instead of c:\Users\user\Documents\Python Scripts – Haseeb Ayub 3 hours ago
>
> Did you try stackoverflow.com/q/38623138/9406615 ? – Hamza Hathoute 3 hours ago

Adding `"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/opencv"` to my `launch.json` of VS Code solved the problem.

I would like say **THANK YOU** to @Hamza Hathoute for the solution. **THANK YOU** @Andy K and @jonrsharpe for suggesting edits.