# How to make Code Runner in VS Code recognize my current working directory?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

I'm using VS Code with the following steps:

1. `cd` into my `Dev` folder
2. Then write code in the `my_projects` folder

Now inside the `my_projects` folder, it's the root workspace directory and I can navigate to the following folders/files:

```
my_projects/
        > DBHelper
            > dbhelper.py
            > config.ini
        > PortfolioManagement
        > Learning
```

Now when I run dbhelper.py, I tried the following test:

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

I get the following:

```
my_projects
```

But I'm expecting

```
my_projects/DBHelper/
```

How do I get Code Runner in VS Code to recognize that the file that I'm currently in, which in this case `dbhelper.py` is in the current working directory?

The reason I ask is because I created a `Database` class using postgres and whenever I use `dbhelper` in different folders, it's not recognizing the config.ini file I have in that directory.

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out. In my VS Code settings, I added these settings:

```json
{
    "python.pythonPath": "/Users/anaconda/bin/python",
    "code-runner.executorMap": 
    { 
        "python": "$pythonPath -u $fullFileName" 
    },
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.terminal.executeInFileDir": true,
    "code-runner.fileDirectoryAsCwd": true
}
```

Comment: `"code-runner.fileDirectoryAsCwd": true` did it for me

Answer (score 2):

I went to the Code Runner settings from the Extensions listing from the VS Code GUI. I found a setting 'Code-runner: File Directory as CWD' and set that on. That fixed my issue, not sure if that was what the JSON above does.

Comment: It's the same as the JSON settings. All the settings in the UI are translated and stored to a settings.json file. See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations

Answer (score -1):

When you open a folder to work in and there are other folders inside, the scripts will get launched in the original folder you have opened and not in the directory where the script is inside in.

For me, a quick fix was to just open the directory where the python file is saved.

But you can change this behaviour by enabling the setting:

```
python.terminal.executeInFileDir
```

1. Go to "File -> Preferences -> Settings"
2. Then search for `python.terminal.executeInFileDir` in the top search bar.
3. Once you find it, activate/enable that option.

But you can't expect `my_projects/DBHelper/dbhelper.py` from `os.getcwd()`. Instead, you will get `my_projects/DBHelper`.

Comment: Hey thanks.  I have that option checked actually.  That didn't work unfortunately for me.  Its a macbook pro.

Comment: That's weird, before i posted, i checked myself that the answer works under Windows. I would like to check under macOS but my Macbook runs Linux :(. For a temporary fix try my quick fix of opening the folder where the script is inside.

Comment: Or you use
`from pathlib import Path`
`filepath = Path(Path(__file__).resolve()).parent / "dbhelper.py"`
That should work in python 3

Comment: This answer won't work because the question was about running using Code Runner and Code Runner has its _own_ settings.

Answer (score -1):

VS code runs commands from inside the folder you have opened, so if you go to a script inside it, VS Code will start a terminal in the workspace and run the script with `python ./DBHelper/dbhelper.py`.

You can change the integrated terminal CWD by going to the workspace settings and adding `terminal.integrated.cwd`, but I don't think that would solve your problem since you are probably running scripts using VS Code's debugger.

If you are running through the debugger, you can edit your launch.json file (VS Code creates one automatically for the workspace), and add different launch commands for each of your .py files.

Comment: For the part about editing launch.json file, see related Q&A for [How to set the working directory for debugging a Python program in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38623138/vscode-how-to-set-working-directory-for-debugging-a-python-program). But since the question was about Code Runner, it won't work to just set the `cwd` of the terminal or of the debugger, because Code Runner has its _own_ settings.