# What settings do I have to change to make Visual Studio Code automatically run files in the right directory?

Tags: visual-studio-code, python-idle

Coming from IDLE, I am used to be able to just left-click python files anywhere, it'll launch IDLE, and  then pressing **F5** just runs the script. In VSCode however, I have to open the terminal, `cd` into the right directory, and only then can I finally run my python script. Is there a way to change this behavior?

Comment: In Windows, you should be able to right-click and choose Open with Code. To permanently set the application, right-click > Open With > Choose app

Comment: I did that, but the terminal in vs code starts in `C:\Users\user` by default, always...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was recommended to use the Code Runner extention and bound the `Run Code` (`code-runner.run`) command to my **F5** key.

Then I noticed input() not being ran so I had to make sure `code-runner.runInTerminal` was on, but that re-started my problem from the beginning because the terminal was at the wrong working directory and then I finally found the `code-runner.fileDirectoryAsCwd` setting to run it from there.

I think this solution is similar to [this one for the python extention](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62805473/6934388), but I'm not sure if that would cause the whole wrong working directory issue again.

Answer (score -2):

choose from menu file then click on auto save