# Advice for VS Code CWD settings on Windows 11

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to ask some advice for how to set up cwd settings within VS code to make this quicker and simpler.

Currently, my cwd is always set to C:\Users\John. This works fine if I am only running a Python file and a few modules because code runner auto-selects the project's folder, but issues arise when I have to load an image, for example.

The current cwd (C:\Users\John) means I have to define the entire path to an image, or I have use the cd command in terminal, both of which are extra typing.

Is there any setting or extension I can use, that set's vs code's default terminal's cwd to that of the file being run, so that files called within code are picked from the same folder as the file being run?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VSCode -- how to set working directory for debugging a Python program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38623138/vscode-how-to-set-working-directory-for-debugging-a-python-program)

Comment: It's a bit confusing. You mention "*code runner*" but you are asking for "*vs code's default terminal's cwd*". If you are running with code runner, then you need to set code runner's CWD: see [How to make codeRunner in VS code recognize my current working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62805327/2745495). If you running it manually from the terminal, you need to set the terminal's cwd: see [Changing the default path of Visual Studio Code's integrated terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43305050/2745495). If running through VS Code's debugger, see the previous comment.