# Debugging in Visual Studio Code not reading from file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I'm new to Visual Studio Code, I've managed to set up the debugger with mingw but reading from files doesn't work. While running the executable it reads correctly from the file and displays the correct answer but when debugging it always displays 0.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
ifstream f("data.in");

int main()
{
    int n;
    f>>n;
    cout<<n;
}
```

Comment: you should check if the file could be opnened

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to do that but I still don't understand why it works when I run the exe but not while debugging

Comment: Maybe the working directory is different when debugging versus clicking on the file. Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38623138/vscode-how-to-set-working-directory-for-debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38623138/vscode-how-to-set-working-directory-for-debug)

Comment: Likeliest reason is that your program tries to find `data.in` in a different place from where you put it.

Comment: And this is why you should *never* open files using relative paths, *always* use absolute paths. If you need to open a file that is relative to the EXE (or any specific folder), get the EXE/folder's absolute path first, then apply the relative path to it to make a new absolute path, then use that new path to open the file.

Comment: Yes you are right, as I said I'm a newbie so I didn't even know I had to modify the launch.json Thank you all so much!

Comment: I would move `ifstream f("data.in");` into your `int main()` and check and return an error message if the file could not be opened.