# How do I fix visual studio code path error?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

so I have this problem in visual code, when I open a file in the same directory of a project, visual code doesn't identify the file unless I give him the whole directory

This is the image of the error:
[image: This is the image of the error]

Comment: This is not an issue with VS Code. It has to do with how `iconbitmap()` searches the file system and what directory it starts from.

Comment: but it works fine with Pycharm and with python launcher

Comment: It depends on how your python program is launched. I'm pretty sure VSCode doesn't start from the current working directory unless you configure it to do so.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38623138/vscode-how-to-set-working-directory-for-debug

Comment: @SuperStormer Or more accurately, it depends on what the current working directory is when VS Code starts.

Comment: @MoatazHarrabi That's a good point. The underlying concept here is what we call the "current working directory".  Each of the editors you use set this in different ways.

Comment: Correction: VSCode doesn't start programs from the cwd of the *current file* unless you configure it to do so.

Answer (score 1):

**[cwd](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_cwd)**:

Specifies the current working directory for the debugger, which is the base folder for any relative paths used in code. If omitted, defaults to ${workspaceFolder} (the folder open in VS Code).

And you can set it to:`${fileDirname}` - the current opened file's dirname([official docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference))

Answer (score 0):

Try this way to set working directory manually:

```
/tmp/1/
/tmp/2/file
```

```
import os

print("Current working directory: {0}".format(os.getcwd()))

> Current working directory: /tmp/1

open('file', 'r')

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file'

os.chdir('/tmp/2')

open('file', 'r')

> <_io.TextIOWrapper name='file' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

Also you can set directory related to the running python file:

```py
import os
print(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

```
python /tmp/1/file.py

> /tmp/1
```

The good practice is to set application path somewhere in global configuration file