# Why is file creating in parent folder of source code?

Tags: python, file

There is `src` folder witn `env` and `main.py`. I create log file like next and saw file in parent folder of `src`

```py
from loguru import logger
logger.add("logs.txt")
```

[image]

In the other hand like this and file into `src`

```py
dirname = path.dirname(__file__)
log_path = path.join(dirname, "logs.txt")
logger.add(log_path)
```

[image]

What is responsible to root folder when path is only filename? I need to create some files into `src`. I have copy-past code of dirname calculation to each of them. Looks like mistake.

Comment: Maybe because you run your script from parent directory? Try to print the output of `os.getcwd()`

Comment: @Corralien but `main.py` into `src`

Comment: Are you asking why `logger.add("logs.txt")` adds a file in the parent directory?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi why logger create file out of `src` folder when `main.py` into `src`

Comment: Because all relative file paths are relative to the current working directory, which by default is the directory you ran your script from

Comment: Before `logger.add` can you `print(os.getcwd())` to ensure where your script run from, please. If you run your code from spyder or pycharm or other tool, the working directory is the base of your project.

Comment: @Corralien Can I set path to `src` for VS Code debug config?

Comment: Try: [VSCode -- how to set working directory for debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38623138/vscode-how-to-set-working-directory-for-debug). I think it's what your are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, the problem is how the working directory is set in your IDE (VSCode).
Try to modify the working directory in the configuration:

[VSCode -- how to set working directory for debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38623138/vscode-how-to-set-working-directory-for-debug).

A more generic way could be:

```
import os

if DEBUG:
    os.chdir('./src')

logger.add("logs.txt")
```