# VScode debugging Flask. calling to subrocess.Popen() returns no module named error

Tags: python, flask, visual-studio-code

I have a very simple flask application with 2 files app.py and test.py both under same main folder.

> app.py:

```
from flask import Flask
import subprocess

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def home():
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'test.py'])
    return "Hello, Flask!"
```

> test.py:

```
def main():
  print('PING')  

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

I created the virtual environment and added flask into it.
When I run app.py using VSCode Python:Flask debugging I got the **'No module named test.py'** error like below:

- Serving Flask app 'app.py' (lazy loading)
- Environment: development
- Debug mode: on
- Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
- Restarting with stat
- Tip: There are .env or .flaskenv files present. Do "pip install python-dotenv" to use them.
  127.0.0.1 - - [08/Dec/2021 12:03:46] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
  No module named test.py

But when I run it using integrated terminal by 'python -m flask run'
everything works fine and 'PING' being printed like below:

- Tip: There are .env or .flaskenv files present. Do "pip install python-dotenv" to use them. * Environment: production
  WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
  Use a production WSGI server instead.
- Debug mode: off
- Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
  127.0.0.1 - - [08/Dec/2021 12:00:02] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
  PING

I guess I miss some python debugging configuration but cannot realize which one. What should I add in order to fix it during debugging?

Comment: How about `from test import main; main()`?

Comment: Now, the problem is in much bigger application where we need subprocess.Popen to start an async process. Here just a simplified fragment to show that such approach doesn't work in debugging

Comment: Your problem might be related to not [setting the working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38623138/3929826) in VSC. But in gerenal it is better to import the function and run it (directly, in a thread or in a new process).

Comment: It didn't help. I added cwd into launch.json like this:
>
"version": "0.2.0",
 "configurations": [
  {
   "name": "Python: Flask",
   "type": "python",
   "request": "launch",
   "module": "flask",
   "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
   "env": {
    "PYTHONPATH": "${cwd}",
    "FLASK_APP": "app.py",
    "FLASK_ENV": "development"
   },
   "args": [
    "run",
    "--no-debugger"
   ],
   "jinja": true
  }
 ]
}

same result.