# VS Code Python launch.json config to set cwd to specific module directory

Tags: python, json, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, launch

Searching through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38623138/vscode-how-to-set-working-directory-for-debugging-a-python-program), I was not able to find the information I need.

My dir structure in VS Code:

```
ProjectXYZ
|
-module1
```

My launch.json:

```
{
    "name": "Main File: Python",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "module": "module1",
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "justMyCode": true,
    "args": ["--env", "DEV"]
}
```

Regardless of which file I'm on in VS Code, I want to debug `module1`. I then want the cwd to be set to ProjectXYZ/module1 for other purposes. As is, the cwd at breakpoints is ProjectXYZ.

If I add `"cwd": "${fileDirname}"` to the launch.json, it sets the cwd before opening the module and can no longer find my module. Possible values for "cwd" [found here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_settings-command-variables-and-input-variables).

Is my setup possible purely in the launch.json or do I have to set the cwd immediately after launch (also I don't want to do this in production code, only when debugging in VS code).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can set cwd to the absolute path of the **ProjectXYZ/module1**. you have found the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_settings-command-variables-and-input-variables).

> **${fileDirname}** - the ***current*** opened file's folder path

[Set cwd to your desired folder](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_cwd).