# dotnet core test explorer extension for vscode is not finding tests

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

When I run from dotnet test explorer I get the following.

> Finding projects for pattern
> /Users/tommie/dev/.../CrescentAPITests/*Tests* Found 3 matches for
> pattern in folder /Users/tommie/dev/.../CrescentAPITests Evaluating
> match /Users/tommie/dev/.../CrescentAPITests/CrescentAPITests.cs
> Adding directory /Users/tommie/dev/.../CrescentAPITests Evaluating
> match /Users/tommie/dev/.../CrescentAPITests/CrescentAPITests.csproj
> Evaluating match
> /Users/tommie/dev/.../CrescentAPITests/CrescentDBTests.cs Executing
> dotnet test -t -v=q in /Users/tommie/dev/***/CrescentAPITests [ERROR]
> Error while executing dotnet test -t -v=q -

However when I run
dotnet test -t -v=q from the command line the test are found.

> tommie@Tommies-MacBook-Pro CrescentAPITests % dotnet test -t -v=q
> Test run for
> /Users/tommie/dev/.../CrescentAPITests/bin/Debug/net6.0/CrescentAPITests.dll
> (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0) Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line
> Tool Version 17.3.1 (x64) Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All
> rights reserved.
>
> The following Tests are available:
> CrescentDBTests.HandleResultParsing.Pass
> CrescentDBTests.HandleResultParsing.ParseEquipmentResult
> CrescentDBTests.HandleResultParsing.ParseDistanceAlongResponse
> CrescentDBTests.HandleResultParsing.ParseGetTraceResponse
> CrescentAPITests.HandleResultParsing.Pass
> CrescentAPITests.HandleResultParsing.ParseEquipmentResult
> CrescentAPITests.HandleResultParsing.ParseDistanceAlongResponse
> CrescentAPITests.HandleResultParsing.ParseGetTraceResponse tommie@Tommies-MacBook-Pro CrescentAPITests %

I dont know what error the extension gets when executing dotnet test -t -v=q -

Comment: There is no test explorer build in so what package are you using here?

Comment: The code is working when running from the bin/debug directory and not running from main project directory.  So set the working directory : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38623138/vscode-how-to-set-working-directory-for-debugging-a-python-program

Comment: @ralf Its an extension called .Net Core Test Explorer